# Java. Servlet. Необходимо получить из combobox выбранное значение

Tags: java, html, servlet, combobox

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        JDBC jdbc = new JDBC();
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        LinkedList<String> type = jdbc.getDataFromDBType();
        pw.println("<html lang="en">\n" +
                "<head>\n" +
                "    <meta charset="UTF-8">\n" +
                "    <title>Title</title>\n" +
                "</head>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "<select name=Teleph id=Teleph>");
        for (Inf inf1 : inf) {
            pw.println(
                    "<option value="+inf1.getTelephone_email()+">" + inf1.getTelephone_email() + "</option>");
        }
        pw.println("</select>\n");    
response.getWriter().write(""+request.getParameter("Teleph"));
}
```

у меня есть код.
тут я попыталась считать выбранное значение из select name=Teleph. но в результате выдало null. Подскажите как это можно реализовать.

Comment: как вы считывает значение?

Comment: @Mikhail
"request.getParameter("Teleph")"

Comment: вам надо добавить либо form, либо js код на вашу страницу. пот тут можно подробно почитать как работать с формами в сервлетах https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-form-data.htm

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Я добавила, но мне это не помогло

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, Как я поняла, form используется с input, а с select form не надо. в select значение получают через имя select'а

Comment: select - это тоже input. и для отправки данных на сервер нужна форма или js.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman спасибо большое получилось))